# How to have a window on all workspaces?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I'm using Precise (12.04.1) and I'm using Unity. I have 3 workspaces. I want a particular window/application (say firefox) to be present on all workspaces.

This is easy to do on something like LXDE (e.g. Lubuntu) where I just have to right-click the titlebar and select "show on all workspaces". Then no matter which workspace I move to, the desired window/app is present on each one.

I can't find a way to do this in Unity. Please help.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to right-click on the title bar, when the window is not maximized and select "Always on visible workspace"

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I had to restore / un-maximize the window first, otherwise, I couldn't get the right-click menu where I could select "Always on visible workspace." Thanks!

Comment: `gkrellm` doesn't have a titlebar!

Comment: If there is no title bar try pressing "alt" and "space" to open the same menu.

Comment: Is there a way to set it up permanently? so it is preserved between restarts?

Answer (score 28):

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> will display a menu where you will find "Always on visible workspace".

Comment: This is especially useful in MS Edge PWAs where the system title bar and borders (up to now) can't be made visible.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a chrome window, then you need to right click on the title bar, choose "use system title bar and and borders". Then you get a new title bar, right click on it and choose - always on visible workplace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wmctrl` to do this on the command line. If `wmctrl` is not installed, first install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Then, you add sticky property to the window with:

```
wmctrl -r "firefox" -b add,sticky
```

Don't forget to replace `firefox` with the actual window title.

You can also specify the window using window id. See manual of `wmctrl` for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key combination Super (Windows logo key) + S to view all of your workspaces at once. You can than a window from one workspace to another. You can also right-click the title-bar of the window, then Hover over "Move to Another Workspace", then select the workspace number you wish to move the window to.